# How to run Directory.GetFiles() on a password protected directory (drive)?

Tags: c#

I have a network dive, mapped up locally as Z:\
This drive is password protected
I want to run Directory.GetFiles("Z:\Foo"). What code do I write for this to work? How can I enter the user ID and the password required for his drive, prior to calling Directory.GetFiles?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use impersonation: [A small C# Class for impersonating a User](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx)